# Android SQLite Transaction

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to insert into two tables within one transaction, the insert works as when i do it it return the id of the new row for both tables but it look like it is not being committed to the tables

```
db.beginTransactionWithListenerNonExclusive(this);
try{
db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_NAME1, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_ROLLBACK);
db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_NAME2, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_ROLLBACK);

db.setTransactionSuccessful();

} finally {
            db.endTransaction();
            db.close();
}
```

clarification, only when inserting to more than one table it doesn't work, when inserting to one table it work.

note: I checked if the insert operations were successful and they were, but committing the rows to the tables is what fails

Comment: Where are you calling this code and how is `db` set up?

Comment: I have extended extends SQLiteOpenHelper where all the all setup is done.
To give you more information, when i use this same transaction to insert to one table it works, only when trying to insert to more than one tables it doesn't work

Comment: Never use `CONFLICT_ROLLBACK` in a transaction; this could end the transaction before `endTransaction` is called.

Comment: actually what wont be called is when using CONFLICT_ROLLBACK is setTransactionSuccessful(), which is the point of using it.

Answer (score 0):

end and begin transaction after each table, issue can be solved